# Creating an iOS app: Using native mail app questions

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating an iPhone app that uses the native iOS mail app. Is it possible that when the user clicks either cancel or send in the mail app, it can then redirect back to the app itself without having to reopen it?

Is it then also possible that when the user goes to access the mail portion of the app, it can display the mail app within my app in a webview type manner? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change the functionality of another publisher's app, especially Apple's. But it sounds like you can accomplish what your want to do by using [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). It allows you to send an email from within your app, i.e. without leaving it to go to the native mail client.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are doing is just sending emails you can display a `MFMailComposeViewController` to allow user to send emails without leaving the app.